# How to distribute a cx_freeze bundle on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, packaging, cx-freeze

I have a Python3.6 application I've been able to bundle using cx_freeze via `python setup.py bdist_dmg`. If I run the executable created in the `build` folder locally, it works. I'd like to be able to distribute this package to other Mac users, but when I sent the `build` folder to another Mac instance and ran the executable I got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: 
/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
Referenced from: /Users/admin/Desktop/build/exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-
3.6/run
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I thought cx_freeze would make the Python version accessible. The `build` directory contains a .dmg and .app file of my application, along with this exe.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6 folder which contains the executable I want to run, a Python executable, and some other files related to my project. If I try running either the .app or .dmg, nothing happens (on my machine or on another machine). Any help concerning how I can resolve the issues above or another way to turn my app into a distributable OSX package is much appreciated.